# Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us. Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21]

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I was trying to pay for google developer account but I am getting this error

> Your request failed. Use a different payment method, or contact us.
> Learn more [OR-CCSEH-21]

I tried searching a lot but most of them have answers for [OR-CCSEH-05] but not for [OR-CCSEH-21]

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I tried Union Bank of India, it didn't worked
2. I tried State Bank of India, it didn't worked
3. I tried Andhra Bank, it didn't worked
4. I tried Axis Bank, it didn't worked
5. I tried HDFC Bank, it didn't worked
6. I tried Kotak Bank, "finally that worked".

> So my only advice is first keep the details correct and iterate each
> and every card you can try, hopefully one card will be accepted

Comment: That's some bad dev exp :(
Why doesn't this gets fixed by Google

Answer (score 2):

For my Turkish colleague;

1. QNB didn't worked
2. Kuveytturk didn't worked
3. Yapıkredi worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This solved the problem for me:

1. Sign in to Google Pay [https://pay.google.com/]. I noticed that this page is the "parent" to Google Development Account payment, e.g., you can have different payment methods for your personal gmail extra storage and your business google development account. They show up under the "Subscriptions and services" tab. Also, errors seem easier to handle here.
2. At the top-right corner, select Alerts. This is the "Bell/notification" icon.
   If you have a red alert, take care of that. In my case, I have not chosen a Backup payment method in addition to the Primary method.
3. Refresh the page to make sure there is no critical Alert left.
4. Go to "Payment methods" tab and "Add payment method". In my case when I entered the card numbers, an old address of me populated in the address and zip code fields. I simply changed that to my legal address and that worked! However, when I did the same action in the google development account payment page, I was getting the [OR-CCSEH-21] (on Safari) or [OR-CCSEH-24] (on Chrome) errors. I could not find where Google is reading the old address from (probably a bug)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience this is happening because the bank card doesn't support Automatic payment option which is required for auto renewal. If a card with Automatic payment option is provided, the payment will go through.

When I got a card from my bank with Auto payment enabled, it worked for me. The issue started with RBI's (Reserve Bank of India) restriction on Merchants storing customer card details.